# Hair curves tips

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, sculpting, hair, path

[image]

Hi , i'm using basic hair curves for modeling hair , but i was wondering if there is a way to make the hair just like the sketch on the right , with multple tips ( using only one curve ).

Comment: I found out how to do it

Comment: It would be great for this Q&A platform if you share your solution with us and write an answer in which you solve the puzzle. Thank you!